# error regarding selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

Here is my selenium webdriver code when i run the script i get an error

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[0]/th"}
Command duration or timeout: 48 milliseconds

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class DropdownCommands{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-table");
        String sRow = "1";
        String sCol = "2";

        //Here we are locating the xpath by passing variable  in the xpath
        String sCellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[" + sRow + "]/td[" + sCol + "]")).getText();
        System.out.println(sCellValue);
        String sRowvalue = "Clock Tower Hotel";

        //First Loop will find the 'Clock tower Hotel' in the first column
        for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
            String sValue = null;
            sValue =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/th")).getText();
            if(sValue.equals(sRowvalue)){
                for(int j=1; j<=5; j++){
                    String sColumnValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td["+ j +"]")).getText();
                    System.out.println(sColumnValue);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving "i" value in "for" loop as 0, but there is no tr[0], tr starts with tr[1]. Hence you are getting "Unable to locate element" error.

Modify code as below. It will work.

for(int i=1; i<5; i++){
            String sValue = null;
            sValue =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/th")).getText();
            if(sValue.equals(sRowvalue)){
                for(int j=1; j<=5; j++){
                    String sColumnValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText();
                    System.out.println(sColumnValue);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

### Output:

Saudi Arabia
Mecca
601m
2012
2